# Why does usage of java.nio.files.File::list is causing this breadth-first file traversal program to crash with the "Too many open files" error?

Tags: java, nio, java-io

#### Assumption:

`Stream`s are lazy, hence the following statement does not load the entire children of the directory referenced by the `path` into memory; instead it loads them one by one, and after each invocation of `forEach`, the directory referenced by `p` is eligible for garbage collection, so its file descriptor should also become closed:

```
Files.list(path).forEach(p -> 
   absoluteFileNameQueue.add(
      p.toAbsolutePath().toString()
   )
);
```

---

Based on this assumption, I have implemented a breadth-first file traversal tool:

```
public class FileSystemTraverser {

    public void traverse(String path) throws IOException {
        traverse(Paths.get(path));
    }

    public void traverse(Path root) throws IOException {
        final Queue<String> absoluteFileNameQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        absoluteFileNameQueue.add(root.toAbsolutePath().toString());

        int maxSize = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (!absoluteFileNameQueue.isEmpty()) {
            maxSize = max(maxSize, absoluteFileNameQueue.size());
            count += 1;
            Path path = Paths.get(absoluteFileNameQueue.poll());

            if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
                Files.list(path).forEach(p ->
                        absoluteFileNameQueue.add(
                                p.toAbsolutePath().toString()
                        )
                );
            }

            if (count % 10_000 == 0) {
                System.out.println("maxSize = " + maxSize);
                System.out.println("count = " + count);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("maxSize = " + maxSize);
        System.out.println("count = " + count);
    }

}
```

And I use it in a fairly straightforward way:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileSystemTraverser traverser = new FileSystemTraverser();
        traverser.traverse("/media/Backup");
    }

}
```

The disk mounted in `/media/Backup` has about 3 million files.

For some reason, around the 140,000 mark, the program crashes with this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /media/Backup/Disk Images/Library/Containers/com.apple.photos.VideoConversionService/Data/Documents: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:427)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
    at java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3451)
```

It seems to me for some reason the file descriptors are not getting closed or the `Path` objects are not garbage collected that causes the app to eventually crash.

#### System Details

- OS: is Ubuntu 15.0.4
- Kernel: 4.4.0-28-generic
- ulimit: unlimited
- File System: btrfs
- Java runtime: tested with both of OpenJDK 1.8.0_91 and Oracle JDK 1.8.0_91

---

Any ideas what am I missing here and how can I fix this problem (without resorting to `java.io.File::list` (i.e. by staying within the ream of NIO2 and `Path`s)?

---

#### Update 1:

I doubt that JVM is keeping the file descriptors open. I took this heap dump around the 120,000 files mark:

[image: VisualVM Heap Dump]

#### Update 2:

I installed a file descriptor probing plugin in VisualVM and indeed it revealed that the FDs are not getting disposed of (as correctly pointed out by cerebrotecnologico and k5):

[image: VisualVM File Descriptor Tracing]

Comment: @NwDx I think that question is for older versions of Ubuntu that were not using `systemd`, but `upstart`.

Comment: did the usage of try-with-resource change anything? If not, you might try to use the .sequential() directly after stream()

Comment: Yes, try with resources fixed the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like the Stream returned from Files.list(Path) is not closed correctly. In addition you should not be using forEach on a stream you are not certain it is not parallel (hence the .sequential()).

```
    try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(path)) {
        stream.map(p -> p.toAbsolutePath().toString()).sequential().forEach(absoluteFileNameQueue::add);
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me, as i was reading millions of files and no Linux system changes required. HOPE HELPS ANONE

Answer (score 7):

From the Java documentation:

"The returned stream encapsulates a DirectoryStream. If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed"

Answer (score 4):

The other answers give you the solution.  I just want to correct this misapprehension in your question which is the root cause of your problem

> ... the directory referenced by p is eligible for garbage collection, so its file descriptor should also become closed.

This assumption is incorrect.

Yes, the directory (actually `DirectoryStream`) will be *eligible* for garbage collection.  However, that does not mean that it *will be* garbage collected.  The GC runs when the Java runtime system determines that it would be a good time to run it.  Generally speaking, it takes no account of the number of open file descriptors that your application has created.

In other words, you should NOT rely on garbage collection and finalization to close resources.  If you need a resource to be closed in a timely fashion, then your application should take care of this for itself.  The "try-with-resources" construct is the recommended way to do it.

---

You commented:

> I actually thought that because nothing references the Path objects and that their FDs are also closed, then the GC will remove them from the heap.

A `Path` object doesn't have a file descriptor.  And if you look at the API, there isn't a `Path.close()` operation either.

The file descriptors that are being leaked in your example are actually associated with the `DirectoryStream` objects that are created by `list(path)`.  These objects will become eligible when the `Stream.forEach()` call completes.

> My misunderstanding was that the FD of the Path objects are closed after each forEach invocation.

Well, that doesn't make sense; see above.

But even if it did make sense (i.e. if `Path` objects did have file descriptors), there is no mechanism for the GC to *know* that it needs to do something with the `Path` objects at that point.

> Otherwise I know that the GC does not immediately remove eligible objects from the memory (hence the term "eligible").

That really >>is<< the root of the problem ... because the eligible file descriptor objects will >>only<< be finalized when the GC runs.

Comment: I actually thought that because nothing references the Path objects and that their FDs are also closed, then the GC will remove them from the heap. My misunderstanding was that the FD of the Path objects are closed after each `forEach` invocation. Otherwise I know that the GC does not immediately remove eligible objects from the memory (hence the term "eligible").

Comment: A `Path` object doesn't have a file descriptor.  The file descriptor that is being leaked is the file descriptor for the directory that is used by the DirectoryStream that is returned by `list(path)`

Comment: Looks like there's a communication issue here between you and me and I can not articulate my thiught in a way that you can understand. I am not interested in arguing either. I had a problem, it is now resolved. End of story.

Comment: @Behrang - .... until you run headlong into another problem with the same underlying cause, and you wish you had really understood it :-)